# How to view backing fields for C# auto properties in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio's debugger sometimes gets into a state where it is unable to evaluate expressions. This prevents it from displaying property values. For example, if you're looking at a thread where the top of the stack reports `[Managed to Native Transition]`, and you look at any properties through, say, the `this` reference in the Locals window, they will all report `Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack`.

You can still inspect fields when the debugger is in this state, because that does not require the ability to execute code. (The reason properties become unavailable is that the debugger actually runs the getter to retrieve the value. It can't do that if the thread you're on is buried in some unmanaged code.)

Unfortunately, the compiler-generated fields that stored the value for C# auto properties don't show up in the debugger. (These are the fields with names like `<MyProperty>__BackingField`.)

I've tried enabling the "Show raw structure of objects in variables window" setting in the debugger options, but that doesn't appear to help with these hidden fields.

Is there some way to get the debugger to show me fields that the compiler has hidden?

Or alternatively, is there some other way I can discover the value of an auto property's backing field when the usual property evaluation is unavailable?

---

**Note**: rewriting the code to use a manually implemented property isn't an option in this case, because the property whose value I want to know is in a Microsoft library. (Specifically, the Open XML SDK.) It's an auto property, and I can't change that.

**Also note**: simply allowing the code execution to proceed a little so that it can return from the native code transition isn't an option because for some reason, the code has entered some sort of tight busy loop - it's consuming a CPU core, and never returns. (I'm trying to diagnose that problem which is why I'm trying to find out what the object's property values are - I'm trying to get an accurate picture of how it gets into this state.)

**One more note**: this is not a duplicate of [Acessing the backing field in an auto property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648718/acessing-the-backing-field-in-an-auto-property) - my question is very specifically about reading the value while debugging.

Also, in case it's relevant, I'm debugging the code remotely as it runs on an Azure worker role. The problem only occurs in that environment. This rules out native debugging as far as I can tell, so I can't even go and look at the bit of code that's stuck in a loop - I'm having to try an infer what it was up to by looking at the managed code that was running immediately before it disappeared off into that rabbit hole.

Comment: Too bad you are not in VB.NET, if you where [adding `_PropertyName` to the watch list would work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293589.aspx#sectionToggle0), but it does not work for the C# compiler.

Comment: Do you need to be able to do anything further (single step or run) the program at the point you've stopped at? If not, it might be time to take a dump of the process and fire up WinDbg/SOS - at least then you can find the location of objects in memory and inspect them.

Comment: A process dump is probably the next step. I was hoping to avoid that, as I've had symbols issues when debugging dumps from Azure roles before, but they're just tedious rather than insurmountable. (Symbols all just work when debugging Azure remotely from VS.) At least it'll let me look at the native code in which it has apparently hung.

Comment: @Ian Griffiths: Even if you have a dump and solved your symbol issues...the debugger would still hide the fields when debugging the dump...okay maybe you could read the memory to get the values.

Comment: Ah, but once you've got a dump file you can open it up in WinDbg. Nothing can hide from WinDbg. It reaches the parts that the VS debugger cannot reach.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a class with a property you want to watch in a debugger:

```
public class C
{
    // ...
    public int I { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I believe the following watch expression will work (`c` is an instance of class `C`):

```
c.GetType().GetField("<I>k__BackingField",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(c)
```

Not very convenient, I know, but better than nothing.

Comment: This does not work, you get the same complaint from the watch window as the property "Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack". [Here is a quick example program](http://pastebin.com/xF15ppRF) to test it, just start the program then pause it once the form is shown. Add the watch `program.GetType().GetField("<Test>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(program)`, click the button to evaluate the function and you will get the error message.

Comment: Scott is correct. The reason I need to do this in the first place is that the thread being debugged has locked up hard, so I can't run managed code at all. Inspecting fields still works, but unfortunately the debugger hides the field.